# not able to access a network drive using credentials in php

Tags: php, authentication, mapping, network-drive, net-use

I am working on a php code as shown below in which **I am making a connection to network drive using credentials**.

**Php code:**

```
$user = 'mickeymouse';

$password = 'helloworld';

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-ST-001\Video_Remap\podcast\" /user:"'.$user.'" "'.$password.'" /persistent:no');    // Access a network drive using credentials

$src_dir = ('\\\INVEST-ST-001\Video_Remap\podcast\incoming_folder'); 

$destination_dir = ('\\\INVEST-ST-001\Video_Remap\podcast\outgoing_folder');

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-ST-001\Video_Remap\podcast" /delete /yes');                                     // Then deleting it

$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir)); // Line D
```

I also made a connection through net use command:

```
net use "\\INVEST-ST-001\Video_Remap\podcast" /user:"mickeymouse" "helloworld" /persistent:no
```

and I got the following message:

> The command completed successfully

The version of php which I am using is:

> PHP version: 5.3.28

**Error:**

The error which I am getting on the webpage is:

> The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in
>   W:\ahdhd\shshshs\status.php on **Line D** in the php code above.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **php code above** or any other **net use command I need to use** in order to make a connection 
to network drive using credentials in php.

**Edited:**

I am able to access everything inside **test** directory but not inside **Audio_Remap** directory.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking the occurences of backslashes? To me it looks like you have too many of them inside your `exec` call

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for checking. It was working before. As soon as I restarted the server everything stopped before.

Comment: @NicoHaase I will share more information.

Comment: @NicoHaase I am able to access everything inside **test** directory but not inside **Audio_Remap**. Inside **test** directory I don't need any kind of credentials.